# Cancel hide behaviour on mouse over in jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, delay, show

I am having what must be a relatively common issue.

Please consider the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="\\jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <style>
            #div{
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabz1">1 tab</div>
        <div id="tabz2">2 tab</div>
        <script>
            $('div[id*="tabz"]').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).delay(1000).hide("slow");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like this code to do is the following:

1. On mouseout of the div hide it after the delay (great, this works).
2. If the mouse re-enters the div then cancel 1.

My question is; how do I get 2 to work

I thankyou for any help and apologise if this question has been asked before.

Comment: correct your css markup `#div` there is no id exists named this. `div{}`

Comment: You want to re-enter inside a hidden div? How is this possible?

Comment: well because there is a delay of 1000 ms it is still possible for the user to hover the mouse back into the div until the delay until hide is passed. The idea being normally you don't want a drop down menu to disappear instantly after the cursor has left the div.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery api sais that it cannot be canceled.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

maybe you should use setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue with this:

```
    $('div[id*="tabz"]').mouseout(function(){

        $(this).delay(1000).slideUp('slow');

    });

    $('div[id*="tabz"]').mouseover(function(){

        $('div[id*="tabz"]').stop() 

        $('div[id*="tabz"]').show(function() 
        {
        $('div[id*="tabz"]').removeAttr('style')
        });  

    });
```